# how can i make my character die when it falls off the screen?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, lua, coronasdk

I'm developing a Doodle Jump like game. Big problem: i take some part of the code from GitHub, and now i would like to implement the function that we know in Doodle Jump which makes the character die when he falls off the screen

I've tried something like that:

```
local function falling()

    if(player.y > display.contentHeight + 100) then 
        gameIsRunning = false
        scoreLabel:setFillColor(1,0,0)
    end
end

Runtime:addEventListener("fall",falling)
```

here you have my github link to the code (can't post it because of the format) -> https://github.com/valeriova96/JumpJump.git

expected: the penguin is no more visible (he is below the screen), then the game stops

actual: the penguin is no more visible (he is below the screen), the game continues playing but i can't see the penguin

Comment: Your Github project don't include game.lua file so I can't check it.

Comment: first of all, thank you so much for your time, second I have committed it if you want  you can try and check

Comment: I got error: "attempt to concatenate global 'sceneName' (a nil value)" You don't use composer in game.lua so there is no scene to go to. Add it.

Comment: solved!!!!!! i added a variable in the pre collision function which saves the y ccordinate of the player.  Then, in the enter frame function i compare that coordinate with the actual y coordinate of the player, if it is higher then the one of the pre collision (plus 1000 - magic number- ) then the player dies

Answer (score 0):

I didn't exactly get your question, but if you want to make game stop there will be 2 ways depending on your scenario : 
1- go to new scene in this function
2- create a popUp view and show message
also for removing your object do this : 
player:removeSelf()
player= nil
it will fully remove your player display group from memory